# How to use Optional as an omissible parameter in pattern-match?

Tags: pattern-matching, optional-arguments

Below is a function intended to test if an expression is a polynomial in which all the coefficients and exponents are integers:

```
intPolyQ[Optional[_Integer] + 
Plus[Optional[_Integer] x_Symbol^Optional[_Integer] ...], x_] := True;
intPolyQ[___] := False;
```

It gives unexpected results in some cases. For example,

```
intPolyQ[#, x] & /@ {x, 2 x, 2 x + 1, 2 x^2 + 3 x, 2 x^2 + 3 x + 1}
```

gives

```
{True, True, True, False, True}
```

which is wrong in the 4th case.

Why does this happen? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't quite understand why, but one needs **both** patterns (Jens' and ywdr1987's) to get `True` for all the expressions in the example. This can be done using `Alternatives` or adding an additional definition to cover the pattern in Jens's answer:

```
ClearAll[intPolyQa];
intPolyQa[HoldPattern[Optional[_Integer] + Plus[Optional[_Integer]
  x_Symbol^Optional[_Integer] ...]],  x_] := True; 
intPolyQa[Optional[_Integer] + Plus[Optional[_Integer] 
  x_Symbol^Optional[_Integer] ...],  x_] := True;
intPolyQa[___] := False;
intPolyQa[#, x] & /@ {x, 2 x, 2 x + 1, 2 x^2 + 3 x, 2 x^2 + 3 x + 1}
(* {True, True, True, True, True}  *)
```

or

```
 ClearAll[intPolyQb];
 intPolyQb[Alternatives[HoldPattern[Optional[_Integer] + 
  Plus[Optional[_Integer] x_Symbol^Optional[_Integer] ...]], 
  Optional[_Integer] + Plus[Optional[_Integer]
      x_Symbol^Optional[_Integer] ...]], x_] :=  True;
 intPolyQb[___] := False;
 intPolyQb[#, x] & /@ {x, 2 x, 2 x + 1, 2 x^2 + 3 x, 2 x^2 + 3 x + 1}
 (* {True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: You're right (+1).

Answer (score 10):

The problem isn't with `Optional` but with the fact that `Plus` will evaluate pattern sequences as in `_ + _` to get unpleasant results like `2 _`. In your pattern, you can prevent this by simply wrapping everything in `HoldPattern`:

```
intPolyQ[HoldPattern[
    Optional[_Integer] + 
     Plus[Optional[_Integer] x_Symbol^Optional[_Integer] ...]], x_] :=
   True;
intPolyQ[___] := False;
```

With this, the function seems to work fine **if you also retain  your old definitions** as @kguler observed:

```
intPolyQ[#, x] & /@ {x, 2 x, 2 x + 1, 2 x^2 + 3 x, 2 x^2 + 3 x + 1}

(* ==> {True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

Of course there is also an easier way to test for integer polynomials - let's call the polynomial `poly`, then you could just do

```
And @@ IntegerQ /@ CoefficientList[poly]
```

Comment: With your definition of `intPolyQ`, it turns out that `intPolyQ[#, x] & /@ {x, 2 x, 2 x + 1, 2 x^2 + 3 x, 2 x^2 + 3 x + 1}` returns `{False, False, False, True, False}` in my computer! What's wrong!? @Jens

Comment: `MatchQ[list, {__Integer}]` is much faster than `And @@ IntegerQ /@ list` to check for a list of Integers.  @ywdr1987  `CoefficientList[#, x] ~MatchQ~ {__Integer} & /@ {x, 2 x, 2 x + 1, 
  2 x^2 + 3 x, 2 x^2 + 3 x + 1}` returns `{True, True, True, True, True}` here.

Comment: Oh yes, you need both patterns as @kguler observed. I got `True` everywhere because I must have not exectuted the `Clear` so I did have both your and my definitions.